# Prevent inserting duplicate records

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi, unidac

For the sake of learning I have created two identical tables in SQLite and was trying to figure out how to prevent inserting duplicates from one table to another. 
I am using this query in trying to find out if duplicates exist before posting the record.
However, it does not work right since duplicates still get inserted and no warning message appears.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
UNIQuery1.Close;
UNIQuery1.SQL.Clear;
UNIQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT * FROM TEMP2 WHERE DATE=:F1 AND user=:F2';
UNIQuery1.Params.ParamByName('F1').Value:=UNITable1.FieldByName('DATE').Value;
UNIQuery1.Params.ParamByName('F2').Value:=UNITable1.FieldByName('USER').Value;
UNIQuery1.Open;
if UNIQuery1.isempty then begin  
UNIQuery1.Close;
UNIQuery1.SQL.Clear;
UNIQuery1.SQL.Text:='INSERT INTO TEMP2 (DATE,USER) select DATE,USER FROM TEMP1';
UNIQuery1.ExecSQL;
UNITable2.Refresh;
end
else
ShowMessage('Record already exists !');
end;
```

Can someone enlighten me on how to do this right ? Table has only 3 fields : ID (Autoinc),DATE(date) and USER (char).Both are identical. So basically I want the program to tell me that the USER and the DATE already exist in the table I am trying to post identical records.

EDIT ; Using Sir Rufos query weird things happen:

[image]

Comment: Create a unique index on `(date, user)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite has a built in function to prevent violating the constraints.

[ON CONFLICT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html)

Build a unique constraint on the fields `Date` and `User` and you can insert the new values with

```
insert or ignore into TEMP2 ( Date, User )
select Date, User from TEMP1
```

But it seems that SQLite did not get the uniqueness if one of the fields contains the `NULL` value.

To check if the the target table contains the values (containing `NULL` or not) you have to

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM TEMP2 
WHERE 
  COALESCE( "DATE", '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ) = COALESCE( :DATE, '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ) 
AND 
  COALESCE( "USER", '' ) = COALESCE( :USER, '' )
```

---

**UPDATE**

Your approach will not work, because you only check the **current row** from `TEMP1` but insert **all** rows from it into `TEMP2`.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Prepare the queries

  // check duplicates query
  UNIQuery1.Close;
  UNIQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM TEMP2 WHERE COALESCE( "DATE", '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ) = COALESCE( :DATE, '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ) AND COALESCE( "USER", '' ) = COALESCE( :USER, '' )';

  // insert data query
  UNIQuery2.Close;
  UNIQuery2.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO TEMP2 (DATE,USER) VALUES (:DATE,:USER)';

  // walk through TEMP1
  UNITable1.First;
  while not UNITable1.EOF do
  begin
    // check current row of TEMP1 for duplicates
    UNIQuery1.Params.ParamByName('DATE').Value := UNITable1.FieldByName('DATE').Value;
    UNIQuery1.Params.ParamByName('USER').Value := UNITable1.FieldByName('USER').Value;
    UNIQuery1.Open;
    // if no duplicates found
    if UNIQuery1.IsEmpty then 
    begin
      // insert the data
      UNIQuery2.Params.ParamByName('DATE').Value := UNITable1.FieldByName('DATE').Value;
      UNIQuery2.Params.ParamByName('USER').Value := UNITable1.FieldByName('USER').Value;
      UNIQuery2.ExecSQL;
      // delete current entry from TEMP1
      UNITable1.Delete;
    end
    else
      // next row from TEMP1
      UNITable1.Next;
  end;
  // refresh
  UNITable1.Refresh;
  UNITable2.Refresh;
end;
```

But for this you have to be careful in multi-user-scenarios. Someone can insert the same data in the small time gap between checking this *soft constraint* and inserting the data.

And this are hard to find failures

Comment: Setting Unique constrain on the mentioned datafields and running "UNIQuery1.SQL.Text := 'insert or ignore into TEMP2 ( Date, User ) select Date, User from TEMP1';" also insert duplicate record X2 (Twice !).

Comment: Not understanding you....Why are you searching for duplicates in table1 when I should do that in table2?

Comment: you can fiddle that constraints for yourself here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/447fb/1

Comment: Where do I look for duplicates in `Table1`? I check if the current row from `Table1` is already in `Table2` and if not then I insert it in `Table2`.

Comment: Sorry to hear that - it works for me on sqlfiddle.com - so please post your not working example on sqlfiddle.com

Comment: I have tested your constraints on SQLite and they do work. Now I need to test this in Delphi.But if choose to stay with your suggestion to use the constraints,how do I flash the message that duplicates are trying to be inserted? Sqlite just ignores the insertion so user must now that nothing happened. Sorry for not replying quickly,I am having some strange issues with my mouse. Was going to post pics of why the query suggestion does not work but I cant seem to select the text with the mouse.

Comment: I updated my answer due to **new informations** (using `NULL` values) in your question

Comment: Yes,I've managed to port the constraints to Delphi "UNIQuery1.SQL.Text:='INSERT OR IGNORE INTO TEMP2 ( "date", "user" )SELECT "date", "user" FROM TEMP1';" does the job. Any way I can warn the user of the ignore factor ?

Comment: No, then you have to insert them one by one. I've updated my answer and all inserted rows will removed from `TEMP1`. All not inserted row remain in table `TEMP1`.

Comment: I get stuck on the "UNIQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM TEMP2 WHERE COALESCE( "DATE", '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ) = COALESCE( :DATE, '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ) AND COALESCE( "USER", '' ) = COALESCE( :USER, '' )';"   [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(56): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon ...[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(64): E2029 ';' expected but 'WHILE' found ... ???

Comment: Do you remember that you have to double the quotes? `SELECT '' FROM foo` has to be `SQL.Text := 'SELECT '''' FROM foo';`

Comment: I am getting 'parameter USER not found' !?